# Download file from

Tags: excel, vba

Thanks for this excellent resource, it has been of great assistance to me, but I am having a problem using excel VBA to download excel files from a remote server. I suspect it is something obvious that my code is lacking.

The problem I am having is that all the downloaded files are always 15KB in size, regardless of the size or content of the original file and all bear the same content which appears to be text simply copied from the host website, rather than the file I am trying to download. I have tried using various file extensions including CSV but the results are the same.

When I open the downloaded file excel says the file format and extension don't match and then says that, due to problems during load, the file is "missing file C:\remote\css\logon.css" and "missing file C:\remote\javascript\ramjsfx.menu.css", which is Greek to me.

```
    Sub DownloadFilefromWeb()

Const E_OUTOFMEMORY As Long = &H8007000E
Const E_DOWNLOAD_FAILURE As Long = &H800C0002

Dim InitialName As String
Dim Msg As String
Dim RegExp As Object
Dim RetVal As Long
Dim SaveName As String
Dim SavePath As String
Dim URL As String

URL = InputBox("Enter the download URL below.", "Download from Internet")
If URL = "" Then Exit Sub

Set RegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
RegExp.IgnoreCase = True
RegExp.Pattern = "^(.*\/)(.+)$"
InitialName = RegExp.Replace(URL, "$2")
Set RegExp = Nothing

If InitialName = "" Or InitialName = URL Then
MsgBox ("Error - Missing File Name")
Exit Sub
End If

SavePath = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialName)
If SavePath = "" Then Exit Sub
'SavePath = "C:\Users\Rob's Laptop\Documents\Test\Test3.xls"
'URL = "https://remote.picosting.co.uk/Remote/fs/files.aspx?path=%5c%5cPISBS2011%5cfiles%5cRob%  20Shaw%27s%20test%20folder%5cTest1"

RetVal = URLDownloadToFile(0&, URL, SavePath, 0&, 0&)

Select Case RetVal
Case 0
Msg = "Download Successful"
Case E_OUTOFMEMORY
Msg = "Error - Out of Mmemory"
Case E_DOWNLOAD_FAILURE
Msg = "Error - Bad URL or Connection Interrupted"
Case Else
Msg = "Unknown Error - " & RetVal
End Select

MsgBox Msg

End Sub
```

Kind regards

Rob

Comment: I use this vbscript code albeit not VBA. http://vbscriptautomation.net/73/download-files-using-vbscript/

Answer (score 0):

`URLDownloadToFile()` is literally and simply downloading the .aspx page that is on the server - when accessed through a normal web broswer, that page does server side logic to obtain and download the Excel file you are trying to get. The css files it is complaining about are stylesheet files that are used to control the display of the .aspx page.

You will need to use something more complex than `URLDownloadToFile()` to save the file that you want, for example setting up an IE Application object as described here:
http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/502298-need-help-regarding-ie-automation-using-visual-basic-applications.html